# Delay Keyframes per defined time and keep opacity 0 after animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, delay, opacity

I've been using HTML5 and Css3 to build an animated banner, but I have a few issues I can't find a work around for at the moment.

Heres a quick bit of code to use for an example, imagine this is a div layer with an image assigned to it.

First off is Opacity, it works until the end of the timeline animation then re-appears, is there a css way to get round this or would I have to use javascript?

Secondly is transition delay, I would of thought I could do a keyframe delay and freeze it for a few seconds inbetween each transition, but it never takes effect. If anyone can help I'd aprpeaciate it!

```css
@-webkit-keyframes animation {
   0% {
       opacity:1;
       -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
       -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
   }
   50% {
       -webkit-transition-delay:10s;
       opacity:1;
       -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
       -webkit-transform: translateY(300px);
   }
   100% {
       opacity:0;
       -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-inout;
       -webkit-transform: translateY(900px);
   }
}
#animation {
   -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   -webkit-animation-name: animation
}
```

FIrst off is the delay command, Transition-delay and animation-delay, both

************Update*************************

Opacity is solved, to get it to finish after the animation, have your First frame 0% set to opacity 0. If that's a problem set a frame to 1% set it to opacity 1.

Then add forwards on the end of your animation i've been doinbg it shorthand so something like this.

```
#bannerImg {
        -webkit-animation: bannerImg-animation1 3s 0s 1 ease-in-out forwards}
```

Comment: It might help to clarify, but as for opacity, you have 0% opacity:1; Thus it'll keep getting visible then, and fading out from 50-100%.  If you want to gradually fade in, and it's not, have 100% be opacity:1; and 75% opacity:0;  
To get it to freeze, just have the animation stay the same for x%.  Ex, Copy the 100% and make the same exact thing for 80%.  Thus between the two nothing happens.  There might be better ways, but off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to make the code nice to look at but since starting delays and animations from within an animation itself does not seem to work I stuck the following together:

```
@-webkit-keyframes animation {
   0% {
       opacity:1;
       -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
       -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
   }
   18.75% {
       opacity:1;
       -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
       -webkit-transform: translateY(300px);
   }
   81.25% {
       opacity:1;
       -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
       -webkit-transform: translateY(300px);
   }
   100% {
       opacity:0;
       -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-inout;
       -webkit-transform: translateY(900px);
   }
}
#animation {
   -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 16s;
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   -webkit-animation-name: animation;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c44Zn/)
This solution just uses `18.75%` and `81.25%` as markers for the delay, changing nothing during that time (10 seconds).